# EF MVC RAZOR: How to decode HTML Encoded strings of a PartialView output?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, decode, encode

I am using EF4 + MVC 3 with Razor.

I have the following `ActionResult`, which renders a `Dictionary<string,string>` into a partial view.

**ACTION**

```
public ActionResult combotest()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> r = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    r.Add("<> ''", "T");
    ...
    return PartialView("_mypartial", r);
}
```

Now, special chars contained into the `Model.Key` values are HTML Encoded, while I'd like to use them as plain text. For example `<> ''` is rendered as `&lt;&gt; &#39;&#39;`.

I tried to convert them with `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` or `Server.HtmlDecode` without success:

**PARTIAL VIEW** (_mypartial):

```
<select>
    <option value=''></option>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> value in (Dictionary<string, string>)Model) 
    {
        <option value="@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(value.Key)">@value.Value
     </option>
    }
</select>
```

Could you help me? I would avoid to use `String.Replace`, if possible.

Comment: Could you specify what went wrong with the other two approaches?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To display text unencoded you can use `@Html.Raw(value.key)`

Answer (score 2):

Larry,

try this:

```
  <select>
     <option value=''></option>
       @foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> value in (Dictionary<string, string>)Model) {
         <option value="@Html.Raw(value.Key)">@value.Value
     </option>
   }
   </select>
```

Html.Raw() returns an HtmlString instance that wraps the original string.
The Razor engine knows not to escape HtmlString instances, thus display is as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using 'string' in the first place, but rather `IHtmlString`, for example with `HtmlString`.

For example:

`public ActionResult combotest()
    {
        Dictionary<IHtmlString, string> r = new Dictionary<IHtmlString, string>();
            r.Add(new HtmlString("<> ''"), "T");
            ...
        return PartialView("_mypartial", r);
    }`

`<select>
     <option value=''></option>
       @foreach (KeyValuePair<IHtmlString,string> value in (Dictionary<IHtmlString, string>)Model) {
         <option value="@value.Key">@value.Value
     </option>
   }
   </select>`

Now, you don't have to rely on an implicit security contract between the view (using Html.Raw) and the controller (providing text that is hopefully safe).  You're providing valid, safe Html and marking it as such from the source.